# Checking user visits | PHP

Tags: php

Ok so I store the User ID and a PHP Timestamp on a db. What I want to do is check whether the user has visited on a daily basis. Something very similar to SO's visited system. I know that I should have the user's visit record.

But what I can't imagine right now is how do I determine the days that the user has visited and not visited. Any ideas? I really can't piece it together some help would be appreciated. A simple point to the direction if its ok. thanks

---

**Edit**:

I want to know the days the user has visited. Literally if the user visited on Nov. 1, 2013. I want to identify that but it wouldn't be just one day it would be each day since the user registered.

Comment: visit entries -> days with visits -> count

Comment: You can just keep a field populated with last visit timestamp when user logs in, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Deadpool Do you want to calculate the number of consecutive days?

Comment: I want to know the days the user has visited. Literally if the user visited on Nov. 1, 2013. I want to identify that but it wouldn't be just one day it would be each day since the user registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append your user table with the following columns:

- visittime
- visitcount
- consecutive (boolean)

When a user visits, check if the visittime was more than a day ago, and update `consecutive` accordingly. Als increment visitcount if visited consecutively.

Comment: `Rows` or `columns` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches to solve this problem.

The most common way is to create a new table in your database.

This table should contain an "access log" of yout users (on entry per user per day). This way you can check if the user has accessed the site or not on a particular day. With this information you can calculate (almost) any information regarding to access stuff.

The fields coud be:

- user_id
- visit_time
- visit_count
- consecutive (tiny int)

You could add those fields to your existing table as well, but I think an additional table is cleaner.

This should get you up and running I guess.

Answer (score -1):

So I suppose your main problem is how to determine if visitor is new or not.

You can use a `$_COOKIE` for that (as google analytic do), incrementing it for each visitor (this will be your visitor-unique-id)

Then if the cookie  and you is not present, this is a new visitor.

Then store every page loading you want in a db